# How to set values after chart is rendered in Flot?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, flot

I'm currently using Flop to display a chart on my website. It's a chart with one series of data and the x-axis is set to time-mode. Now I have some buttons to change the spectrum of view ("Show all", "Show last six months", "Show last year", etc.) but I don't know how to change a specific attribute without overwriting the current plot. Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
$("#six-months-scope").click(function () {
    $.plot("#fd-weight-graph", data, {
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            min: <?php echo $newestEntry . " - 15552000000" ?>,
            max: <?php echo $newestEntry ?>
        }
    });
});
```

But if I'm doing it like this, I also have to set every single option (e.g. set color, lines, points, etc.) and I think it's an inefficient solution. I just want to **change** the min and the max attribute.

In addition, if I'm setting the min and the max attribute to an axis, the chart does not start at the date I set, but before and it ends after the date I set. $newestEntry is the date of the newest entry in the dataseries and I want the point of it to stick to the right end of the chart. I hope you understand what I mean.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update with new data and new axis min/max and then redraw the chart I do:

```
 // somePlot is flot plot object saved from your initial $.plot call
 somePlot.setData(newData);
 somePlot.getOptions().xaxes[0].min = newMin;
 somePlot.getOptions().xaxes[0].max = newMax;
 somePlot.setupGrid();
 somePlot.draw();
```